# How to create such a layout in android?

Tags: android-layout, android

Im trying to create a layout in android, but failing with my current attempt, I hope anyone here can help me.
The layout is this:
[image]

the best attempt  I got is this:

```
<GridLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:id="@+id/rangeLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="From"
            android:id="@+id/fromLabel"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/fromEditText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:editable="true"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:numeric="integer|decimal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="To"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/toEditText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:numeric="integer|decimal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:editable="true" />

    </GridLayout>
```

The problem is that the two edit boxes are not at the center. 
What else do I need to do in order to acheive that?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="5.0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edittext1"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/edittext1"
        android:text="From:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="9.0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edittext2"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/edittext2"
        android:text="To:" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Android Studio screenshot]